# Decomposition of calcium carbonate in a sealed vessel

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, equilibrium

For the equilibrium

$$\ce{CaCO3(s) <=> CaO(s) + CO2(g)}$$

$\Delta H^\ominus = 178\ \mathrm{kJ\ mol^{-1}}$ and $\Delta S^\ominus = 160\ \mathrm{J\ mol^{-1}}$.

I'm asked to suppose that $1\ \mathrm{mol}$ of $\ce{CaCO3}$ and $1\ \mathrm{mol}$ of $\ce{CO2}$ are heated reversibly in a closed vessel under a pressure of one bar.

How much $\ce{CaCO3}$ is present in the container when the temperature reaches $1100\ \mathrm K$?

I know that at this temperature $\Delta G^\ominus = 2\ \mathrm{kJ\ mol^{-1}}$ and $K_p = 0.80$. I'm thinking that since the equilibrium constant $K = p(\ce{CO2})/p^\ominus$ is less than $1$, then the $\ce{CO2}$ would combine with any $\ce{CaO}$ around to make $\ce{CaCO3}$, but since there isn't any the composition must remain unchanged at $1\ \mathrm{mol}$ $\ce{CaCO3}$ and $1\ \mathrm{mol}$ $\ce{CO2}$. Is this right?

Now suppose the temperature reaches $1120\ \mathrm K$, at which $K_p = 1.14$. Some of the $\ce{CaCO3}$ will start to decompose, right? Suppose $n$ mol do, so that I have $1-n$ mol of CaCO3, $n$ mol of $\ce{CaO}$ and $1+n$ mol of $\ce{CO2}$.

How do I find $n$?

Comment: Is your system Isobaric or Isochoric?

Comment: Isochoric, I assume, since the vessel is described as "closed".

Comment: In that case Gibb's free energy equations are not appropriate.  You should use Hemholtz energy for an isochoric system.

Comment: Hmm, you're right. If the pressure is constant, then the volume must change, though?

Comment: Well a closed system can expand, it just cannot exchange matter

Comment: The system is isobaric, the question specifies "under a pressure of 1 bar".

Answer (score 2):

At $\pu{1100 K}$, $\Delta G>0$, favouring the backwards reaction. The backwards rate is 0, as there is no $\ce{CaO}$ present. Therefore, at $\pu{1100 K}$ there is 1 mole of $\ce{CaCO3}$ present. At $\pu{1120K}$, $\Delta G<0$ and the decomposition is favoured. See my working below to show why the decomposition goes to completion:
[![showing decomposition goes to completion][1]][1]

$$\ce{CaCO3(s) <=> CaO(s) + CO2(g)}$$

Let's say $\ce{A <=> B + C}$. We start with 1 mol of $\ce{CaCO3}$ and 1 mol of $\ce{CO2}$. What is the extent of the reaction, given the equation composition for $\Delta G < 0$ in a closed vessel at $\pu{1 bar}$

$$ G_{tot} = \sum_i\left(n_i\mu_i\right) \implies G_{tot} = n_\ce{A}\mu_\ce{A} + n_\ce{B}\mu_\ce{B} + n_\ce{C}\mu_\ce{C}$$

Let $\alpha$ be the degree of dissociation, Recall $n_\ce{A} = 1$, $n_\ce{C} = 1$ initially

So,

$$G_{tot} = (1-\alpha)\mu_\ce{A} + \alpha\mu_\ce{B} + (1+\alpha)\mu_\ce{C}$$

As $\ce{A}$ and $\ce{B}$ are solids, $\mu_{A} = \mu_\ce{A}^\circ$ and $\mu_{B} = \mu_\ce{B}^\circ$

$\ce{C}$ is gaseous so we use, $\mu_{A} = \mu_\ce{C}^\circ + RT\ln \frac{P_\ce{C}}{P^\circ}$ (since C is assumed to be a perfect gas)

We now have,

$$G_{tot} = (1-\alpha)\mu_\ce{A}^\circ + \alpha\mu_\ce{B}^\circ + (1+\alpha)\left(\mu_\ce{C}^\circ + RT\ln\frac{P_\ce{C}}{P^\circ}\right)$$

$P_\ce{C} = P^\circ$ due to the pressure being 1 bar within the container.

$\therefore$ Rearranging we get,

$$\begin{align}G_{tot}  &= \mu_\ce{A}^\circ + \mu_\ce{C}^\circ + \alpha (\mu_\ce{B}^\circ + \mu_\ce{C}^\circ - \mu_\ce{A}^\circ) \\  &= \mu_\ce{A}^\circ + \mu_\ce{C}^\circ + \alpha \Delta G^\circ (< 0) \end{align}$$

Therefore $G_{tot}$ is minimized at maximum $\alpha$, i.e. $\alpha = 2$

Thus at 1120 K, we have 0 moles $\ce{CaCO3}$. Physically, this is rationalised as there being no entropy of mixing between the reactants and products. The same rationale can be used to explain why there is no ice present in liquid water above 273.15 K at atmospheric pressure.

Answer (score 0):

You are right that at $\pu{T_o}$ = $1100~\mathrm{K}$ there will not be any decomposition of $\ce{CaCO3}$ in the presence of $\ce{CO2}$.

But, as the temperature increases further to $\pu{T_{1}}$ = $1120~\mathrm{K}$, $\ce{CaCO3}$ starts decomposing because at this temperature $Q_\mathrm p < K_\mathrm p$.

As the reaction is taking place in a closed container of volume $V$, by viewing the reaction mixture as an ideal gas mixture, we can calculate the amount of $\ce{CaCO3}$ decomposed at $1120~\mathrm{K}$:

$$p_o(\ce{CO2}) \times V = 1 \times R \times 1100 \tag1$$
$$p_o(\ce{CO2}) = 0.80 \mathrm{bar}$$
$$p_1(\ce{CO2}) \times V = (1+n) \times R \times 1120 \tag2$$
$$p_1(\ce{CO2}) = 1.14 \mathrm {bar}$$

On solving, $n= 0.399$.

Comment: The system is isobaric, the question specifies "under a pressure of 1 bar". – orthocresol♦ Jan 17 at 12:33